# Allow delete permission in order_lines in sale order

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I want to give delete access on order_line to a group until they click Save in Sale-order. Once they click Save they should not be able to edit that . I am doing this because sometimes when the user from that group is working if he accidentally adds a records in order_line. He should be able to delete that until he saves the order. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Saving` of a record mean two things:

1) Creation of a new record. The `create` method is invoked

2) Updating an already existing record. The `write` method is invoked

In both cases you are able to revoke the rights you have given to a particular group of users by overriding `create` or `write` (or both) and inside that method you create or modify a rule in `ir.rule`

Example: User with UID = 4 clicked save:

```
def write(self, vars):
    # either create a rule
    self.env['ir.rule'].create({//TODO})
    # or modify an already existing one
    self.env['ir.rule'].write({'domain'://TODO})
    return super(self, classname).write(vars)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not be an issue. The order line record is not actually created in the database until the Save button is clicked, therefore the user should only need create access to sale.order.line.

[image: Sales Order Lines Example]